# In selenium web driver,I can able to click the save button then page getting saved but it shows no such element error message not able to go futher

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

To check Fifth Tab */

```
        boolean fifth_a=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='RadTabStrip2']/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span")).isDisplayed();
        boolean fifth_b=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='RadTabStrip2']/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span")).isEnabled();
      String Depression5="";
      if(fifth_a==true && fifth_b==true)
      {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='RadTabStrip2']/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      WebElement text5=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='RadTabStrip2']/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span"));
      Depression5=text5.getText();
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("No tabs");
      }
      if(Depression5.equals("Depression"))
      {
      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
      driver.switchTo().frame("ctl00_C5POBody_EncounterContainer");
      driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pageViewEncounter']/iframe")));

      driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='RadPageView1']/iframe")));

      save(driver);
      } 

      else
      {
         System.out.println("Opened window is not depression");
      }

  /* End of Fifth tab check */}

public void save(WebDriverdriver)throws InterruptedException,NoSuchElementException
      {

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rdbtn Not At All Little interest or pleasure in doing things-Depression-0']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='DLCLittle interest or pleasure in doing things-Depression-0_txtDLC']")).sendKeys("pleasure in doing things-Depression");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rdbtn Nearly Every Day Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless-Depression-1']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return;
     }
```

In selenium web driver,I can able to click the save button and when driver try to execute the next line, it shows error as No such element. I tried more things but can able to clear this issue. Please check the error message.

```
                  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
                (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.65)
                (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448
  (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 1.06 seconds
 For documentation on this error, please visit:  

http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'ACURUS154', ip: '172.18.1.111', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\kannank\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir912_9689}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=43.0.2357.65, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 8c312dccc74442e2a744c7b03d5ccf28
Command duration or timeout: 1.51 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:        

http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome=     {userDataDir=C:\Users\kannank\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir912_9689}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=43.0.2357.65, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=30794df9-bc88-439e-825d-11dff1e33c7b, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
   Session ID: 30794df9-bc88-439e-825d-11dff1e33c7b
```

Comment: Do you getting that exception after this line ? driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click();

Comment: But after that line nothing to find....you have just passed thread ..Also remove 'return' , what it returns?

Comment: After executing the Save action, it shows error as above. While executing last line it shows error.

Comment: Last line means "Return"??

Comment: yes. When we remove that return line also, it shows error after Thread.sleep;

Comment: Are you sure that it is clicking perfect on save button?driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click();

Comment: yes in my application, the entered data gets saved.

Comment: then it should not give any error. remove Thread.sleep(3000);
        return;

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the element is not loaded while you are doing the checks or you had a mistake in the xpath. Also, you are playing around with frames and that could get tricky.

It is difficult to tell without debugging, for that I recommend:

1) Keep the elements in a variable and check if they are null before calling "click()" to identify the problematic element.

2) Use commands such as "WaitFor..." to add time restrictions instead of sleep, to break if the element is not found by that time. That would give you hints.

3) Try to use assertions that allows for text output to help you find out the issue.

Maybe you are in the wrong frame? As an advice, return to default content right after you finish with the frame and not before you start. Also, consider that elements within a frame can take longer to load than the rest of the page or the frame itself.